# Android, list view adapter for different type of items

Tags: android, listview

I have to create Android application which will show list view with different types of items. For example, folders (which only have name) and sale item (which have name, picture, price and some other attributes).

What the best way to implement such use case?

Comment: check out this post :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layouts-for-each-row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set data to your item ( in adapter )
If typeItem is folders make gone to attributs Which you don't want to show
TextViewName.setVisibility(View.GONE)
....etc 
Or can you use getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType() in Adapter.

Comment: Thanks, but make gone to attributes is not the case because the view for folder and sale item is too different. For the getViewTypeCount() thanks. I will check it